# Mongorestore - meteor application no longer working after restoring a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, docker, meteor, mongorestore

One of my collections became corrupt and was required to be restored. I used mongorestore to recover the collection, now when running the meteor production application - it doesn't return any data. Have I missed a step to refresh meteor to look at the new collection?

Comment: Maybe a typo when you restored the data? Bear in mind, when a collection does not exist, then MongDB creates a new collection automatically. Also when you select from an non-existing collection, you get just an empty result - not an error like many other database systems.

Comment: No, the collection is named correctly. I was wondering is there an issue because the meteor application is in a separate docker image? For some reason it can't find the restored collection?

Comment: What you describe should have worked. Please provide more details for debugging including: e.g., a query run from inside a mongo shell with result (findOne is enough), the same query run from meteor (with result), a different query from Meteor against a different collection that still works.

Comment: Is it possible that because the UUID for the collection has change the meteor application can no longer consume the data?